# ROS install for rplidar

Tags: ros, ubuntu, mapping

i plan to install ROS in may raspberry 4 8gb question what version of ubuntu support ROS because 20.04.3 is old version and not available in ubuntu website please help me

Answer (score 0):

Usually all Ubuntu versions works with some version of ROS. It depends on which ROS version you want to use. I would recommend using ubuntu 22.04 as it is a LTS version and with that ROS2 Humble or any other version after Humble. You can go to [official ROS documentation page](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation.html)  for checking which ROS version works with which Ubuntu version.You can also check out [ROS 2 on Raspberry Pi](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Installing-on-Raspberry-Pi.html) for more details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure in what ROS version you want to use.
If the ROS you mentioned means ROS1, then the version of ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic(final release of ROS1) is recommended.
ROS1 is difficult to use in later versions.
However, if what you said means ROS2, using ubuntu 22.04 and ROS Humble is recommended.